# I want to create a program that generates a random password and asks the user to guess the password

Tags: java, computer-science

I am creating a program that generates a random password and asks the user to guess the  generated password.
The problem I'm facing now is how to compare the generated password to the inputted password
My program compares the length of both passwords, but I don't know any possible way to compare both passwords to see if they're the same or not
The program has to compare both passwords and after three attempts, the program has to output the generated password
The code below is my program

```
    final static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String method(int len){
   String ASCII = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
        int count =0;
         int rand;
        System.out.println("Guess the generated password");
        String key = in.nextLine();
         for(int i=0;i<key.length();i++){
        count++;
    }
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
         rand= sr.nextInt(ASCII.length());
        sb.append(ASCII.charAt(rand));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            if(len!=count){
            System.out.println("The length of the random generated password is "+ len+ " and the  length of the password inserted is " + count);
             System.out.println("The length of the generated password and the length of the inserted password varies. Please try again...");
             System.out.println("Guess the generated password again");
         key = in.nextLine(); 
        }
    
       }
        return sb.toString();
    
    }

 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      

       
        Random r = new Random();

        int len;
        len = r.nextInt(1, 8);

        System.out.println("length :" + len);
        
          System.out.println(method( len));

    }

}
```

Comment: `sb.toString().equals(key)`, perhaps?

Comment: Well, @JustAnotherDeveloper has given you the answer, but this is possibly the most difficult game ever!! In 3 tries you gotta guess one among 52PN possibilities ??
Let me know if someone wins, I might as well ask the winner to pick a lottery for me.!

Answer (score 0):

You have made some strides in your coding since this post was originally placed. **Based on your newest code shown below (from the post you deleted):**

```
final static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String method(int len) {
    //Create a variable to hold the ASCII character
    String ASCII = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
    int count = 0;
    int rand;
    System.out.println("Guess the generated password");
    String key = in .nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        count++;
    }
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rand = sr.nextInt(ASCII.length());
        sb.append(ASCII.charAt(rand));
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        while (len != key.length()) {
            System.out.println("Length do not correspond please try again");
            key = in .nextLine();
        }
        if (len == key.length() && !sb.toString().equals(key)) {
            System.out.println("Length correspond but passwords differ, Try again");
            key = in .nextLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.print("The correct password is: ");
    return sb.toString();
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create a random length generator
    Random r = new Random();
    int len;
    len = r.nextInt(1, 7);
    System.out.println("lungezza :" + len);
    System.out.println(method(len));
}
```

When generating a random number within a specific range like 1 inclusive to 7 inclusive then do it this way:

```
// int len = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; thus...
int len = new Random().nextInt((7 - 1) + 1) + 1;
```

Don't add a bunch of whitespaces in your `ASCII` String variable. Consider not having whitespaces at all or if you have to, just provide one between the Upper and lower letters, for example:

```
String ASCII = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

I say this because potentially, there is a good chance your random password generation **could** create a password that is all whitespaces which really isn't a password at all.

Also, I know your compiler isn't complaining but readers of your code will....consider using proper naming conventions for your variables, etc. `ASCII` should be `ascii` or even `aSCII` unless it is going to be a class **Field** variable which it is not. It is currently considered a method **local** variable. You actually did this correctly in this older post.

You can not guess an auto-generated password if that auto-generated password has not been generated yet. The code which auto-generates the password to guess is currently **after** the first prompt which asks you to supply what it is.

Move the code that generates the password **above** the code that asks the first prompt of what that password might be, for example:

```
//Create a variable to hold the ASCII characters
String ascii = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    
// Generate the secret password to guess...
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
int rand;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    rand = sr.nextInt(ascii.length());
    sb.append(ascii.charAt(rand));
}
    
// Guess the password...
int count = 0;
System.out.print("Guess the generated password: -> ");
String key = in .nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    count++;
}
```

This `for` loop under the first Guess prompt:

```
int count = 0;
System.out.print("Guess the generated password: -> ");
String key = in.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    count++;
}
```

is not required. All it does is count the number of characters contained within the first password guess. Ironically, you already know this by just using the `key.length()` method. You don't use the `count` variable for anything anyways so you may as well just get rid of all that:

```
// Guess the password (3 guesses)...
System.out.print("Guess the generated password: -> ");
String key = in .nextLine();
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    while (len != key.length()) {
        System.out.println("Lengths do not correspond please try again");
        key = in .nextLine();
    }
    if (len == key.length() && !sb.toString().equals(key)) {
        System.out.println("Lengths correspond but passwords differ, Try again");
        key = in .nextLine();
    }
}
System.out.print("The correct password is: ");
return sb.toString();
```

In reality, you only need one prompt and it's always nice to validate the User's input. Here is an alternative way to do this:

```
private final static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
private static int numberOfGuessesAllowed = 3;
private static boolean correct = false;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create a random length generator
    Random r = new Random();
    int len = r.nextInt((7 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    System.out.println("Password to guess contains " + len + " characters.");
    System.out.println("You have " + numberOfGuessesAllowed + " attempts to guess it right!");
    System.out.println(method(len));
}

public static String method(int len) {
    //Create a variable to hold the ASCII characters
    String ascii = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    
    // Generate the secret password to guess...
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    int rand;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rand = sr.nextInt(ascii.length());
        sb.append(ascii.charAt(rand));
    }
    String secretPassword = sb.toString();
    
    
    // Guess the password...
    String key = "";
    while (key.isEmpty() && numberOfGuessesAllowed > 0) {
        System.out.print("Guess the generated password (q to quit): -> ");
        key = in .nextLine().trim();
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            return "Quitting! Bye-Bye.";
        }
        if (key.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry! Try again...\n");
        }
        else if (secretPassword.equals(key)) {
            correct = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (len != key.length()) {
            numberOfGuessesAllowed--;
            System.out.println("Lengths do not correspond! Please try again.\n");
            key = "";
        }
        else if (len == key.length() && !secretPassword.equals(key)) {
            numberOfGuessesAllowed--;
            System.out.println("Lengths correspond but passwords differ, Try again\n");
            key = "";
        }
    }
    
    if (correct) {
        System.out.print("You guessed it! The password is: ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("You couldn't do it! The correct password is: ");
    }
    return secretPassword;
}
```